# A characterization of Borel measurability

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I need help proving the following  fact.   Let $(X,\textbf{X})$ be a measurable space.  Then $f:X \to \mathbb{R}$ is **X**-measurable iff $f^{-1}(E) \in \textbf{X}$, $\forall E \in \textbf{B}$.

Defns and notations: $X$ is a set, **X** is  a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $X$, $f^{-1}(E):=\{x \in X: f(x) \in E \}$, **B** is the $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ generated by open intervals $(a,b)$. $f$ is **X**-measurable means $f^{-1}( \alpha, \infty) \in \textbf{X}$, $\forall \alpha \in \mathbb{R}$.

What I have: "$\leftarrow$" is easy since $( \alpha, \infty) \in \textbf{B}$.   I'm struggling with the formal way to argue "$\to$".  Informally, I know the preimage $f^{-1}(E)$ is well-behaved wrt the operations of unions, intersections, complements, etc:
$$f^{-1}(\cup_{i=1}^\infty E_i)=\cup_{i=1}^\infty f^{-1}(E_i), f^{-1}(E^c)=(f^{-1}(E))^c$$  Thus, since everything in **B** is generated by those operations starting from open intervals $(a,b)$, we should have that, starting from sets of the form $f^{-1}(a,b)$ and applying the same operations, we "stay" in **X**.
Sorry I'm new to measure theory and still trying to pick up how proofs of this nature are done.

Comment: You probably mean that $f^{-1}(\alpha, \infty) \in \textbf{X}$, not in $\textbf{B}$ in the definition in the second paragraph.

Comment: I fixed it, thx for the catch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** show that $\mathcal{B}$ is generated by $\{(-\infty,\alpha]\}_\alpha$. If you already know that $\mathcal{B}$ is generated by the open sets, this should be straightforward.

You will need the theorem below as well.

> **Theorem**: Let $(X,\mathcal{M})$ and $(Y,\mathcal{N})$ be given. Assume $\mathcal{N}$ is generated by $\mathcal{E}$ (i.e. $\mathcal{N}=\sigma(\mathcal{E})$). If $f\colon X\rightarrow Y$ satisfies
>   $$
> E\text{ is in }\mathcal{E}\implies f^{-1}(E)\text{ is in }\mathcal{M},
> $$
>   $f$ is measurable.

*Proof*: Define the pullback
$$
f_{*}(\mathcal{M})=\left\{ E\subset Y\colon f^{-1}(E)\text{ is in }\mathcal{M}\right\} .
$$
The above is a $\sigma$-algebra (convince yourself of this). By assumption,
if $E$ is in $\mathcal{E}$, then $E$ is in $f_{*}(\mathcal{M})$.
Therefore, $\mathcal{E}\subset f_{*}(\mathcal{M})$. Since $\mathcal{E}$
generates $\mathcal{N}$, $\mathcal{E}\subset\mathcal{N}\subset f_{*}(\mathcal{M})$. This implies that all sets in $\mathcal{N}$ are measurable.

Comment: Thx! Letting $(Y,\mathcal{N})=(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B})$ and $\mathcal{E}$ to be the intervals $( \alpha, \infty)$, I see how your argument proves the result.