# Can anyone explain one trivial theorem about measurability of functions?

Tags: measure-theory

I know this is simple, but I just cannot get my head around. Can anyone explain the following?

> if $\mathcal{C} \subset\mathcal{B}$ and  $\sigma(\mathcal{C})=\mathcal{B}$, then
>   $h^{-1}:\mathcal{C}\rightarrow\Sigma$,  => h is $\Sigma$ measurable.

The proof in the book:

Let $\mathcal{E}$ be the class of elements B in $\mathcal{B}$ such that $h^{-1}(B)\in \Sigma$. Then $\mathcal{E}$ is a Sigma algebra. Then $\mathcal{C} \subset \mathcal{E}$.

So how does this prove it?

Comment: Do you mean if $\mathcal{C}\subset\mathcal{B}$, $\sigma(\mathcal{C})=\mathcal{B}$, **and** $h^{-1}(C)\in\Sigma$ for all $C\in\mathcal{C}$, then $h$ is $\Sigma$-measurable?

Comment: No quite, but there was a typo. Just updated

Comment: But what do you mean by "**then** $h^{-1}\colon \mathcal{C}\rightarrow \Sigma$"? You haven't defined $h$ yet.

Comment: The notation of the book i am reading is sloppy. I think it means h is any function whoes preimage from C is in $\Sigma$

Comment: I would guess they meant what I wrote above.

Comment: @par okay, assuming what wrote above, can you explain the proof?

Comment: Ok. Copied and pasted from another question I answered: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1802574/a-characterization-of-borel-measurability/1802650#1802650

Answer (score 1):

> **Theorem**: Let $(X,\mathcal{M})$ and $(Y,\mathcal{N})$ be given. Assume $\mathcal{N}$ is generated by $\mathcal{E}$ (i.e. $\mathcal{N}=\sigma(\mathcal{E})$). If $f\colon X\rightarrow Y$ satisfies
>   $$
> E\text{ is in }\mathcal{E}\implies f^{-1}(E)\text{ is in }\mathcal{M},
> $$
>   $f$ is measurable.

*Proof*: Define the pullback
$$
f_{*}(\mathcal{M})=\left\{ E\subset Y\colon f^{-1}(E)\text{ is in }\mathcal{M}\right\} .
$$
The above is a $\sigma$-algebra (convince yourself of this). By assumption,
if $E$ is in $\mathcal{E}$, then $E$ is in $f_{*}(\mathcal{M})$.
Therefore, $\mathcal{E}\subset f_{*}(\mathcal{M})$. Since $\mathcal{E}$
generates $\mathcal{N}$, $\mathcal{E}\subset\mathcal{N}\subset f_{*}(\mathcal{M})$. This implies that all sets in $\mathcal{N}$ are measurable.